# How to analyze PermGen contents?

Tags: java, permgen

I want to get a dump of the PermGen to see why it is filling. Is there a way to analyze this? I already know about the common suspects like log4j, tomcat webapp reloading etc, but I have some custom proxy generation code in my application, too, and just want to look under the hood.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The PermGen normally consists of the string literal pool and loaded classes. To answer part of your problem, i.e. the string literal pool I wrote a utility to print a running JVM's string literal pool. It is available here:

https://github.com/puneetlakhina/javautils/blob/master/src/com/blogspot/sahyog/PrintStringTable.java

It is based on [PermStat](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/jvm/hotspot/tools/PermStat.java.html), which is the class used to print permgen stats by the jmap tool.

Comment: Great stuff! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Could you please clarify how can we fix "Attaching to process ID XXXX, please wait... Error attaching to process: Timed out while attempting to connect to debug server (please start SwDbgSrv.exe)." on Windows while running this program?

Answer (score 18):

You can use the flags:

```
-XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading
```

They print the identities of classes as they get loaded/unloaded from the permanent generation. If you add `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` you can also track the size of the permgen.

Note that i'm not sure the flags are supported in JVMs other than Sun's.

Another suspect of PermGen out-of-memory-errors is [string interning](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29). Check the places where you intern strings in your code.

Comment: This does not address the actual question ... how to **dump** the permgen heap.

Comment: @Stephen: you are right, but I hoped it would be enough in this case :)

Comment: accepted, because this helped me most, even if it did not completly solve my problem. I found out that 160MB pern gen really were not much enought, after writing a script that parsed my log output and counted the size of all loaded classes. (While reading my comment I see at least 2 WTFs)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to get a list of all classes loaded you can use `jconsole`.  Click on the classes tab then click "Verbose Output".  That will print each class that is loaded to `stdout`.  I found this very useful tracking down a JAXB proxy class issue.

You may have to launch your application with the `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` command line option in order for `jconsole` to attach to it.

Comment: Sorry, my permgen is already nearly full. And I don't know with what.

Comment: This should print out the classes that are filling your PermGen space as they are loaded.  Can you restart your application and turn on this logging?

Comment: Not useful and in fact the same as providing -XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading from the first comment.

Answer (score 4):

Will `jmap -permgen` fit the bill?

See the troubleshooting guide for Java
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html#gbyuu

Comment: No. I already knew about this, but I really need a way to have a look at whats already in there.

Comment: Tried using `-permstat` but just got: `Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process`