# how to start SwDbgSrv.exe in windows 7

Tags: java, windows, permgen

Wanted to analyse perm gen contents. So, tried the utility to print a running JVM's string literal pool (Utility is available [here](https://github.com/puneetlakhina/javautils/blob/master/com/blogspot/sahyog/PrintStringTable.java), from [How to analyze PermGen contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842982/how-to-analyze-permgen-contents))

But I'm getting this error:

> Attaching to process ID 8980, please wait... Error attaching to
>   process: Timed out while attempting to connect to debug server (please
>   start SwDbgSrv.exe).

Any idea how to start `SwDbgSrv.exe` in windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the debug daemon to your Java program by running jsadebugd .  Then you can run the HotSpot Serviceability Agent GUI:

```
java -cp %JAVA_HOME%\lib\sa-jdi.jar sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB
```

and File -> connect to debug server -> localhost.  Although this isn't a programmatic dump of all String literals, you will be able to explore more information about your process.

Answer (score 0):

So I also had this issue while I was trying to use [dumpclass.jar](https://github.com/hengyunabc/dumpclass) which was also giving me this error and I think that's because your `PrintStringTable` and DumpClass both depend on the same underlying `jar/tool/system/framework/whatever` called `sa-jdi.jar`

What it does, I have no idea, one feature it has is taking chunks of my life to figure out how to install...

Anyway from what I can tell after reading all 2(!) StackOverflow questions about it is that the version distributed with the java 1.6 SDK (not JRE, it doesn't come with the JRE - oh you didn't already know that, why?) relies on this thing called `SwDbgSrv.exe` which, I don't know what that is but all you need to know is that the version distributed with the java 1.7 sdk (again SDK not JRE) doesn't use `SwDbgSrv.exe`.

So ultimately what does this all mean? Well it means that if you acquire sa-jdi.jar by googling for it then you'll land up at this site: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsajdijar.htm which has the 1.6 version of the jar which requires SwDbgSrv.exe

This means that if you are using a tool that relies on `sa-jdi.jar` then you definitely want to get the one that doesn't use `SwDbgSrv.exe` which all that really means is using the java 1.7 sdk, instead of the Java 1.6 JRE/SDK, because the version of sa-jdi.jar that comes with the 1.7 sdk doesn't use `SwDbgSrv.exe` and is bundled with it! It will specifically be in the `java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\` folder - at least on windows. Definitely make sure the app

---

So how do you fix this problem: Download the java 1.7 sdk and use the sa-jdi.jar bundled with it. It will not require `SwDbgSrv.exe`

Don't download a random `sa-jdi.jar` from a random website.

---

I guess this is technically a non-answer because I have no idea how to start `SwDbgSrv.exe` in windows 7 :/