# Need to get info about objects in Permgen

Tags: java, memory, permgen

I want to get info about what contents are getting placed into permgen. 
Using "jmap -permstat PID;", i am able to get list of classes, classloaders and no. of bytes occupied but what i really want to see the content of object residing there, to be more specific the content of String literals in permgen.

I tried visualVM but it just provides a graph with no details info.

I checked this post: [How to analyze PermGen contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842982/how-to-analyze-permgen-contents/7626113#7626113) but the code at the link : https://github.com/puneetlakhina/javautils/blob/master/src/com/blogspot/sahyog/PrintStringTable.java doesn't compile.

Is there any other way out or it wont be possible to view object content in permgen?

EDIT:

I have installed MAT on my eclipse setup and generated Heap dump of my program. I am able to visualize heapdump on on MAT but still can't differentiate between heap and permgen memory. Can somebody guide me on this?