# Error injecting constructor, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, soap, jvm, guice

I've seen many many questions related to this error. But I still can't find an answer to my problem.

After adding some more logic to my application, y suddenly get this error.

I've been monitoring PermGen usage with jconsole, and the values are normal until I suddenly get this error, no increase is seen before.

[image: jconsole PermGen usage]

I've tried to increase PermGen memory with `-XX:MaxPermSize`, also tried Class unloading with `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` + `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` but none of that helped.

The error appears to be while injecting a WebService client, that finally provides a Port to make WS calls.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

      1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

This injection (but with other service clients) is done in other classes of the application without any issues.

So, I would like to know if there is anything else I could check, or any directions into finding what the issue might be. If there is any other configuration or implementation that could be useful, please request it.

Comment: You might want to better profile your memory, to see exactly what is taking up space. I'd use another tool in addition to JConsole for that: [Memory Analyzer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer). Take snapshots with JConsole or any other tool, then have it analyzed by Memory Analyzer to see the culprit(s).

Comment: Is the tool also able to analyze PermGen dumps? As all the features I see are related to Heap dumps

Comment: Nope. You're entirely right, I totally skipped the "PermGen" requirement when remembering about MemoryAnalyzer. Sorry for that.

Comment: You might want to fall back on the question ["How to analyze PermGen contents?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842982/180719).